# MySQL query from multiple databases and select random

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to select random entries from a single table based on information coming from two other tables (one saved in a different database). The tables are as follows:

1- In databaseA called "islands" contains:

```
  +-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
        | Field       | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
        +-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
        | id          | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
        | chrom       | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
        | start       | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
        | end         | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |
```

the indexes are:

```
+---------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| islands |          0 | PRIMARY   |            1 | id          | A         |       15991 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| islands |          1 | locations |            1 | line_string | A         |        NULL |       32 | NULL   |      | SPATIAL    |         |               |
```

To select from this database I normally use:

```
SELECT * FROM islands FORCE INDEX (locations)
WHERE MBRIntersects(GeomFromText('Linestring(1 120, 1 120)'), line_string)
```

2 - In databaseB call "Context" contains:

```
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| chrom   | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| site    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| context | char(3) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

There are only 4 possible contexts in this table (which are indexed)

3 - In databaseB called "Entries" Contains:

```
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| chrom       | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| site        | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| methylation | float   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

I would like to select a random entry from the entries table that is located in the context table with a context entry of "CpG", can be located in the "islands" table or not (I have two different searches).

**Update:**

Based on comments below I am using

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT t.chrom, t.site, t.methylation, c.context 
FROM f1 as t INNER JOIN context as c on c.chrom = t.chrom AND c.site = t.site 
WHERE c.context = 'CpG'
) AS s LIMIT 2;
```

To get:

```
+-------+-----------+-------------+---------+
| chrom | site      | methylation | context |
+-------+-----------+-------------+---------+
|     1 |  10003735 |          69 | CpG     |
|     1 | 100063074 |       98.79 | CpG     |
+-------+-----------+-------------+---------+
```

I would like to now join these results to the islands table to get the sites from the first part that are found within island regions (or not). I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT t.chrom, t.site, t.methylation, c.context 
FROM f1 as t INNER JOIN context as c on c.chrom = t.chrom AND c.site = t.site 
WHERE c.context = 'CpG'
) AS s
CROSS JOIN islands as i 
WHERE MBRINTERSECTS(GeomFromText('Linestring(s.chrom s.site, s.chrom s.site)'), i.Line_string)
LIMIT 2;
```

However, this gives me an empty set (it shouldn't).

Comment: What, precisely, is your question? With respect, you have a lot of material in your post, but it's hard to parse out your precise question.

Comment: You have no join or condition on islands - nor is any of it's fields in the result set.  So it becomes a cross join - every row from the other tables gets joined to every row on islands.  Thus there is a copy of every row in the result set for every row in islands.  The limit 2 means you get the first two rows which happen to be the same (as far as the values show in the result set - they map to two different rows in islands).  How do you want to join islands in?  What is the relation?

Comment: @adam I have never done a join or conditions before and not sure how to do it. I would like to use the first select statement to get methylation values at CpG sites. Then I would like to get a specific number of those sites with their methylation values that are located within islands and another specific number that are not located within islands. The islands table only contains regions that are islands so sites that cannot be found in that table would be non-islands.

Comment: You already have a joining condition in your example: `c.chrom = e.chrom AND c.site = e.site`.  That whole select could be written as `SELECT e.chrom, e.site, e.methylation, c.context FROM entries as e inner join context as c on c.chrom = e.chrom AND c.site = e.site WHERE c.context = 'CpG' Limit 2;` (I think - untested).  The only difference might be in performance.  You need to work out what the conditions are that relate the data in the other tables to the islands table, but I can't see that from your question.

Comment: @ Adam - your suggestion for the first part works and is much faster than my original code. Now I just need to find the sites from the first part that are found in the linestring index of the islands table.